# Login failure using Google password keychain on Android

Tags: bug, status-review, login, user-accounts

I use a Google account as a keychain for all my passwords. Until now, I was able to log into the *[Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site on both my MacBook Air and my Android phone using this keychain.

As of yesterday, March 22, I am able to log into the *Electrical Engineering* Stack Exchange site using my MacBook Air, but not using it on Android. When I pull up the login screen on my Android, the email field auto-fills, but the password field remains unfilled. I have tried various no-brain solutions like rebooting, clearing cache, etc. to no avail. Auto logging in on other sites, such as Facebook and [X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twitter) are working fine on my Android. Just Stack Exchange seems to have a problem.

Has any code related to the login window been changed recently?

Per [a suggestion by SamGibson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398658/login-failure-using-google-password-keychain-on-android#comment1330859_398658), I tested an older version of the login window on my Android using the [Wayback Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine). Using this older version of the login window, both the email field *and* the password field were populated.

Comment: I assume on your Mac you use the Safari browser and on Android the Chrome/Chromium browser? Are you able to test with Chrome on the mac?

Comment: No, I use Chrome on both devices. I _think_ one needs to use Chrome to use Google's password manager, but to be honest, I've never tried it with Safari.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy - I don't use the same password management, so I can't repro this. However my *guess* is that there has been a change to SE front end code recently (note the "svnrev" value, extreme bottom right, says "rev 2024.3.22.6753"). || Could you try seeing if old versions of the login page do work with your auto-fill? For example, try this 2023 version from the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20230818011204/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login || I would not actually try to login using that page, but does your auto-fill for the password field work there?

Comment: Yes, the Wayback Machine version populates both the email address AND the password field. Great idea to use the Wayback Machine for testing.

Comment: Yes, the password field was changed to `autocomplete="new-password"` which tells browsers a new, non-stored password should be entered or suggested. That is great for signing up, but completely breaks logging in. We shouldn't be using that value if we're using the same HTML for both login and signup. That's a terrible user experience.

Comment: @animuson it is good that someone admits a mistake, I hope it will actually be translated to actions at some point, i.e. this will be fixed. Thanks.